# How to add multiple bouncing divs with different starting points using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is what I have so far:

```
var vx = 3;
var vy = 2;

function hitLR(el, bounding) {
    if (el.offsetLeft <= 0 && vx < 0) {
        console.log('LEFT');
        vx = -1 * vx;
    }
    if ((el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) >= bounding.offsetWidth) {
        console.log('RIGHT');
        vx = -1 * vx;
    }
    if (el.offsetTop <= 0 && vy < 0) {
        console.log('TOP');
        vy = -1 * vy;
    }
    if ((el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) >= bounding.offsetHeight) {
        console.log('BOTTOM');
        vy = -1 * vy;
    }
}

function mover(el, bounding) {
    hitLR(el, bounding);
    el.style.left = el.offsetLeft + vx + 'px';
    el.style.top = el.offsetTop + vy + 'px';
    setTimeout(function() {
        mover(el, bounding);
    }, 50);
}

setTimeout(function() {
    mover($('.bouncer')[0], $('.bouncyHouse')[0]);
}, 50);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/86xyxvyn/

I am trying to add multiple divs to this sketch so that each one bounces around the black box independently. Ideally, each word would also have a unique starting position (not just in the upper left hand corner).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With a few modifications you can get wanted result. One way to do it would be to set the speed for each `div`, using `data` attribute. 
Then you apply you `mover` function to each div, using their individual speed and position to set new speed and test bouncing.
Instead of using setTimeout, you can use setInterval. Like this:

```
div class="bouncyHouse">
                <!-- using data-vx and data-vy allows to set different speed for each div--!>
                <div class="bouncer" data-vx='2' data-vy='-3'>
                    <span>space</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bouncer" data-vx='-2' data-vy='2'>
                    <span>space</span>
                </div>
                <div class="bouncer" data-vx='5' data-vy='2'>
                    <span>space</span>
                </div>
            </div>
```

The js. It's almost exactly what you had, except I've replaced each `vx` and `vy` by the data specific to each. And the call to mover is made in a `each()` call that iterates each `bouncing` div.

```
function hitLR(el, bounding) {
    console.log($(el).data('vx'), $(el).data('vy'))
    if (el.offsetLeft <= 0 && $(el).data('vx') < 0) {
        console.log('LEFT');
        $(el).data('vx', -1 * $(el).data('vx'))
    }
    if ((el.offsetLeft + el.offsetWidth) >= bounding.offsetWidth) {
        console.log('RIGHT');
        $(el).data('vx',  -1 * $(el).data('vx'));
    }
    if (el.offsetTop <= 0 && $(el).data('vy') < 0) {
        console.log('TOP');
        $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
    }
    if ((el.offsetTop + el.offsetHeight) >= bounding.offsetHeight) {
        console.log('BOTTOM');
        $(el).data('vy', -1 * $(el).data('vy'));
    }
}

    function mover(el, bounding) {
        hitLR(el, bounding);
        el.style.left = el.offsetLeft + $(el).data('vx') + 'px';
        el.style.top = el.offsetTop + $(el).data('vy') + 'px';

    }

    setInterval(function() {
        $('.bouncer').each(function(){

            mover(this, $('.bouncyHouse')[0]);
        });
    }, 50);
```

And you can set starting point in the css directly.

```
.bouncer {
    position: absolute;
    width: 200px;
    color:white;
}

.bouncer:nth-child(2)
{
    top: 30px;
    left: 100px;
}
.bouncer:nth-child(3)
{
    top: 50px;
    left: 200px;
}
```

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qwLpf1vr/